# Can we send client system time on server without Inputstream in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to send client side time (`System.nanoTime()`) over server without using any `InputStream`? I am new java thats why unable to find the solution so far. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ServerClient {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket("localhost",9999);

            PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            System.out.print("Enter Something : ");

            //Long temp2 = System.nanoTime();
            int i = 50;

            InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(System.in);


            BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(rd);

            String temp = ed.readLine();

            pr.println(temp);

            BufferedReader gt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            String tm = gt.readLine();
            System.out.print(tm);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Here is Server side code

```
public class Server {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(9999);
            Socket sock = ser.accept();

            BufferedReader ed = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String tmp = ed.readLine();
            System.out.print("I Recieved :"+tmp);

             PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
             String str = "Yup I got it !!";
             pr.println(str);

        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use blocking NIO which was introduced in 2004 in Java 1.4.

Comment: Is it the **class** inputstream you want to avoid (can do: servlet, rmi,...) or the *concept* of using a socket?